# Some user's images of StackExchange are not displayed on my mac.

Tags: safari, google-chrome, graphics

Since this morning I noticed that some of the user images of this site are not displayed, both on safari and on chrome (all the "fractal" images are displayed, and alo some pictures, but others are not). Is this a problem of StackExchange or of my computer? I have OS 10.10 Yosemite, and the latest versions of safari and chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user images (avatars) are stored on various services, such as [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com). It is possible one or more service is either unavailable or blocked on your network.

If you use a third party [advert](https://adblockplus.org) [blocker](https://www.ghostery.com/) within your browser, you may find some user images are blocked. Some advert blocking software considers single-source/multi-website user images a means of tracking your activity across the Internet, and thus blocks the images from loading.

Comment: I have no advert blocker installed, and on chrome I was displaying every avatar correctly until last night. The change that I made (just yesterday night, coincidence?) was to switch from chrome to safari as default browser, but I do not see how this can affect both browsers, and only on this issue...every other website displays images as before.

Comment: just for information, your avatar is one of the non-displayed ones... ;-)

Comment: My avatar is served directly by StackExchange. Previously, I used Gravatar but noted that was being blocked as a 'social tracker'.

Comment: What URL do you encounter if you control-click a missing user image and copy the image address?

Comment: If I try to open the image in a web page I get an error message: "Safari can't find the server". The link of your image is [http://i.stack.imgur.com/pJulE.jpg?s=64&g=1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pJulE.jpg?s=64&g=1). The server not found is i.stack.imgur.com .

Comment: [i.stack.imgur.com](http://stack.imgur.com) appears [to be available](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://i.stack.imgur.com).

Comment: I changed network (from ethernet to wireless, one is the local network of my department, the other the eduroam network), and everything is ok now. So it seems a problem of the network...strangely enough it is the first time I encounter the problem. Until yesterday everything was ok.